# Turn off DocuSign Consumer Consent Disclosure for recipients

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to disable the Consumer Disclosure feature when creating DocuSign accounts via the REST API?  Basically the equivalent of selecting the "No, I choose not to use a Consumer Consent Disclosure at this time." option under Preferences -> Consumer Disclosure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the way to do it is to have a distributor that has that feature turned off so when you create accounts they are created from  your blueprint (we call it billing plan) with the correct settings.  You should reach out to your partner rep and see if you can set up a distributor that suits your needs.